# Problem with overflow-y: scroll in a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a modal created with the Bootstrap library in which I have several lists that are filled when doing an Ajax search, with a fixed size and the property `overflow-y: scroll`, to be able to have many elements without making a huge page.

The problem is that if I select an item below the list, the entire page scrolls to the position where that item would be without the `overflow-y: scroll` property.

I've tried applying the `overflow: revert` property to keep it static, but it doesn't work for me because on small screens, since these lists have a fixed size, you can't scroll to see everything.

Any idea what I can do?

I share the code with everything already included and simplified to 1 list and white space assigned for other elements to give you an idea more or less.

```js
function selectElement(e) {
  ($(e).attr("seleccionado") == 0) ? $(e).attr("seleccionado", "1").parent().appendTo("#listaSeleccionados").children("label").removeClass("btn-outline-success").addClass("btn-success"): $(e).attr("seleccionado", "0").parent().prependTo("#lista").children("label").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-outline-success");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#modalTest").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $("#lista").html(`<li id="seleccionarTodos" class="mt-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-pill w-100" id="btnSeleccionarTodos" autocomplete="off">Seleccionar todos</button></li>`);
      for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        $("#lista").append(`<li id="elemento` + i + `" class="mt-1">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkElemento` + i + `" seleccionado="0" onchange="selectElement(this)" class="btn-check"  autocomplete="off">
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-success w-100 check-lista" for="chkElemento` + i + `">
                                            <div class="text-start">Elemento ` + i + `</div>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>`);
      }
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

```css
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  max-width: 10px;
  max-height: 10px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(77, 0, 0, 0.192);
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  max-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 78, 78, 0.808);
  outline: 1px solid rgb(133, 84, 84);
}

.modal-content {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.check-lista {
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.check-lista:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02, 1.03);
  z-index: 10;
}

#lista,
#listaSeleccionados {
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="position-absolute top-50 end-50 btn btn-primary btn-lg rounded-pill" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalTest">
            Abrir Modal
        </button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modalTest" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="Modal Test" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="titulo">Modal de prueba</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-md-3">
            <div id="buscarEmpleado" class="col">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 gy-1">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="buscador" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Buscador" aria-describedby="Buscar">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col px-2">
              <ul id="lista" class="list-unstyled p-1 border rounded-4 text-center">
                <li id="seleccionarTodos" class="mt-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-pill w-100" id="btnSeleccionarTodos" autocomplete="off">Seleccionar todos</button></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col px-2">
              <ul id="listaSeleccionados" class="list-unstyled p-1 border rounded-4 text-center oculto">
                <li id="deselTodos" class="mt-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill w-100" id="btnDeseleccionarTodos" autocomplete="off">Deseleccionar todos</button></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div style="min-height:300px">
            <h4>Otras listas</h4>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div style="min-height:100px">
            <h4>Filtros</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer text-center d-block">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success rounded-pill">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `$('.modal-body').scrollTop(1);` to your function statements:

```
function selectElement(e) 
{
    if (parseInt($(e).attr("seleccionado")) == 0) 
    {
        $(e).attr("seleccionado", "1");
        $(e).parent().appendTo("#listaSeleccionados").children("label").removeClass("btn-outline-success").addClass("btn-success");
        $('.modal-body').scrollTop(1); //****

    } 
    else
    {
        $(e).attr("seleccionado", "0");
        $(e).parent().prependTo("#lista").children("label").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-outline-success");
        $('.modal-body').scrollTop(1); //****

    }
 
}
// show.bs --> shown.bs and remove setTimeout:
$("#modalTest").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
     $("#lista").html(`<li id="seleccionarTodos" class="mt-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-pill w-100" id="btnSeleccionarTodos" autocomplete="off">Seleccionar todos</button></li>`);
     for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) 
     {
        $("#lista").append(`<li id="elemento` + i + `" class="mt-1">
                                 <input type="checkbox" id="chkElemento` + i + `" seleccionado="0" onchange="selectElement(this)" class="btn-check"  autocomplete="off">
                                 <label class="btn btn-outline-success w-100 check-lista" for="chkElemento` + i + `">
                                     <div class="text-start">Elemento ` + i + `</div>
                                 </label>
                            </li>`);
     }
  
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll use this as a temporary solution, because as you can see through the developer console of the browser, the modal-body is still quite large because <li> elements are listed to the bottom but hidden, and doing this in the bottom lists on a small screen has the same effect as the above mentioned but in reverse, it moves the whole page to the top.